# S3 PHP SDK: copy_object() fails to update the header

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

When including the header options to copy_object, the headers DO NOT get updated.

Headers don't get updated until I make a separate call using update_object. I hope I'm doing something wrong, but I've tested this 4-5 different ways even getting into the sdk code to poke around.

Is this a bug?

I'm using the latest 1.4.3 SDK

Here is my call:

```
$amazonS3->copy_object( 
    array( //Source
      'bucket' => SOURCE_BUCKET,
      'filename' => $source_file
    ),
    array( //Target
      'bucket' => VIDEO_BUCKET,
      'filename' => $dest_file,
    ),
    array( //Options
      'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PRIVATE,
      'headers' => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem myself and solved it iamdev.  After about a half-day of going insane, I started looking at the actual API rather than just trying to use it.

In sdk.class.php, on line 1690, you'll see the following:

```
 if (isset($opt['metadataDirective']))
 $opt['headers']['x-amz-metadata-directive'] = $opt['metadataDirective'];
 unset($opt['metadataDirective']);
 }
```

This means if you are not copying an object to itself, it will not replace the key, hence not update it.

What worked for me was explicitly setting the metadataDirective in my opts in my call, so:

```
 $amazonS3->copy_object( 
     array( //Source
     'bucket' => SOURCE_BUCKET,
     'filename' => $source_file
 ),
 array( //Target
      'bucket' => VIDEO_BUCKET,
      'filename' => $dest_file,
 ), 
 array( //Options
      'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PRIVATE,
      'headers' => array(
      'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
      'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment'
 ),
 'metadataDirective' => 'REPLACE',
 );
```

Hope this works for you, although this is an old post and you've probably found a workaround.

Best,
HG

Comment: Nice, thanks for that!  I worked around by simply making an additional call to update the header, but I'll be back in that code soon and I'll be sure to use your idea.